# Создать блочные элементы в определенном положении

Tags: html, css

Есть один большой блок `<div id="container">`.

В нём нужно расположить блоки одинакового размера, наподобие таблицы, 4 в ширину и 4 в высоту. Блоки должны быть «резиновыми» и адаптироваться под размер монитора.

Как это правильнее реализовать? Ширину в процентах и отступы задавать.

Answer (score 2):

```css
.item {
  width: 25%;
  float: left;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
</div>
```

Для высоты только фиксировано, flexbox или высчитывать с помощью javascript.

Answer (score 1):

```css
body {
  counter-reset: i;
}

div:after {
  content: counter(i);
  counter-increment: i;
}

div {
  float: left;
  width: 25%;
  /*box-sizing: boreder-box;*/
}
```

```html
<div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div>
```

```css
body {
  counter-reset: r, c;
}

.row {
  counter-increment: r;
  counter-reset: c;
}

.row div:after {
  content: counter(r) "/" counter(c);
  counter-increment: c;
}

.row div {
  float: left;
  width: 25%;
  /*box-sizing: boreder-box;*/
}
```

```html
<div class=row><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div></div>
<div class=row><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div></div>
<div class=row><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div></div>
<div class=row><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Можно сделать на [bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid).

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-3">.col-md-3</div>
    <div class="col-md-3">.col-md-3</div>
    <div class="col-md-3">.col-md-3</div>
    <div class="col-md-3">.col-md-3</div>
</div>
...
```

Comment: А без использования сторонних инструментов?